# Removing a language from language bar in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, language

I want to nuke HRV from my language list:

[image]

but not sure how? Funny thing is I don't even know why it appears in the list since it's not added in time and languages:

[image]
?!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, added HRV into my language list and than removed it which resulted in HRV disappearing from my list